# Decode compressedDepth message from compressed_depth_image_transport

Tags: ros, kinect, compressed-image-transport, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the `compressed_depth_image_transport` to compress a Kinect depth image before letting it go through `rosbridge` (the client won't have ROS or opencv installed, only pip-installed libs).  The image is float32 compressed in png.

On the client, I receive the image encoded in base64 by `rosbridge`. After decoding the base64 string, what I have is bytes that are supposed to be the compressed image. However, I cannot figure out the format of the image. For instance, if I wrtite directly the bytes to a ".png" file, I cannot open it using an image viewer. I also get exceptions if I try to load the bytes using Pillow, pypng, scipy, etc.

How does  `compressed_depth_image_transport` works? I have seen in the source code that it uses `cv::imencode`, does it produce a valid png file content as I expect?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247483/decode-compresseddepth-message-from-compressed_depth_image_transport/) by [gariepya](https://answers.ros.org/users/19385/gariepya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to make it work.

According to [this source file](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/compressed_depth_image_transport/html/codec_8cpp_source.html)
the encoder puts a header at the beginning of the file.  According to [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature), the first bytes of any png are `89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a`. By inspection, I found that the first 12 bytes are the header of `compressed_depth_image_transport` and the rest is a valid png file.

---

Originally posted by [gariepya](https://answers.ros.org/users/19385/gariepya/) with karma: 43 on 2016-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-08**:
Nice one. Thanks for reporting back.

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-02-15**:
Thank you so much gariepya! Removing these first 12 bytes is the solution to the problem with which I honestly wasted days of precious working time.